# I cant find why `.read_csv` cannot make a dataframe for `.shape` to recognize

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib, scikit-learn

Following a machine learning guide here: https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/scikit-machine-learning/

Running Python 3.8, might have a hunch that I need to run it in IPython but I think that opens up a new can of worms.

Also have all imported these libraries installed.

I left `%matplotlib inline` as a comment because i'm not running it in Jupyter.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
#%matplotlib inline

from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix, classification_report

df = pd.read_csv("diabetes.csv")
print(pd.shape)
df.describe()

y = df[diabetes.csv].values
x = df.drop('diabetes', axis=1).values

X_train. X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.4, random_state=42)
X_train.shape, X_test.shape
((460,8), (308,8))

logreg = LogisticRegression()
logreg.fit(X_train, y_train)

y_pred = logreg.predict(X_test)

print(confusion_matrix(y_test, y_pred))
print(classification_report(y_test, y_pred))

plt.show()
```

The error I get when running this code is:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "scikitmlprac.py", line 12, in 
print(pd.shape)
File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\pandas_*init*_.py", line 258, in **getattr**
raise AttributeError(f"module 'pandas' has no attribute '{name}'")
AttributeError: module 'pandas' has no attribute 'shape'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you just have a typo here.
You've tried to print `pd.shape` when it should be `df.shape`. Hence the error.

Comment: Thanks! found new errors but it's outside the scope of the question now